# Vim: how to perform this task every time I open a file?

Tags: macos, unix, vim

For a time I have one vim configuration on my laptop and another on my desktop, so when I edited filed on my Dropbox between the two I would end up with format issues.

Specifically, I had `ffs=mac,unix,dos` on one and `ffs=unix,dos` on the other.

Now thankfully that setup is fixed! Yet stragglers remain (those files which haven't been opened, and converted and saved with the new setup).

Now sometimes when I open a file from where it was saved with an ff of "mac", I get a bunch of `^M`.

So I do:

```
e ++ff=mac
setlocal ff=unix
w
```

To correct the issue.

What works to do this 3 line procedure automatically everytime I open a file?

Or even better how could it work to do it automatically everytime I open a file which has an ff that is not unix?

I've Googled [vim task on every buffer open] and [vim macro on every file open] and haven't seen anything that works.

(I'm sure vim in its seemingly infinite wisdom has something just for this, as it seems to have something just for anything [how did they imagine and make all these features?!].)

Comment: You are probably better off using `grep -rlIP '[\x0d]' *` to find the affected files and running `dos2unix` on them.

Comment: It would work and it would be an extra step, ancillary to my work flow. Do more with less, just add a live to the vimrc I use all the time instead of doing anything additional.

Comment: Cris: The idea would be that once you've converted the files, you would never need to do it again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd hesitate to automatically fix this, but the following autocmd seems to do the job.

```
autocmd BufRead * if line('$') == 1 && getline(1) =~# '\r' | edit ++ff=mac | w ++ff=unix | endif
```

It detects files that consist of only a single line that contains embedded CR characters, and automatically performs the conversion. I'd probably add a `:echomsg` to notify the user, too.

Comment: That's basically the heart of the somewhat complicated script here, for reloading mixed line-ending files in DOS. You could then save the file to write out the line ending change. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_reload_files_with_mixed_line-endings_in_DOS_fileformat

Comment: I'm not looking for a complete hand hold, and yet I decide to ask you: could you explain a little bit this syntax? What do the "pipes" do ? And which words are variables? What's the =~ comparison operator mean? And what do the special symbols '$' and # mean?

Comment: The pipes (`:help :|`) are command separators to put everything into a single line. `=~` is regexp match, with `#` case-sensitive. Basically, it says "if the highest line number is one and the first line contains a carriage return, edit with changed fileformat and write. Vimscript is somewhat quirky, but the `:help` explains all of this very well.

Comment: Oh, and please don't forget to close this question by accepting an answer. Just click on the outlined checkmark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to automate your workaround for a borked setup, fix the setup; i.e. consistently use a certain line ending `'fileformat'` across all platforms, and ensure that this gets properly detected (by including it in `'fileformats'`) on each system!

For Vimscript files, that canonical format would be `unix`, because that is handled both by Vim on Windows and Unix (and Mac, I suppose), whereas `dos` would cause errors when sourcing on Unix.

Comment: It is solid reasoning. And the setup is fixed now. I want to automate the stragglers!

Comment: @ingo, same on Mac. You can safely assume it's just another Unix.